# How reliable is using Taiko guage framework in visual studio?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have Inheritance, Abstraction and calling parent class in Taiko framework using Visual studio as editor?

Comment: I think the place for that question may be here https://github.com/getgauge/taiko

Comment: do elaborate on what you are exactly trying to do, taiko is a tool that provides apis to automate browser for testing.